# Where is a hipster/"bobo" neighborhood in Amsterdam?

Tags: amsterdam

I am looking for a place to stay in Amsterdam and this time I would like to stay in a "bobo" neighborhood of Amsterdam.

I do not know how to translate ["bobo"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourgeois-boh%C3%A8me) (bohemian bourgeois), maybe hipster is the closest. The bohemian bourgeois are rather wealthy people who support the counterculture, and have characteristics like being "urban, environment-friendly, idealist".

So, where could I find some hipster neighborhood?

Comment: Hello Max, I think you should take a look at [what questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) we expect here. In particular, this website is not a travel agent, trying to guess what hotel you will enjoy. There are a lot of tools for that. Usually people search for hotels, hostels, B&B and private apartments. For these, [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com), [Booking](http://www.booking.com), [Hostels.com](http://www.hostels.com/) [AirBnb](http://www.airbnb.com), [Couchsurfing](http://couchsurfing.org/) are the common websites you can look up. Good luck finding your favorite place!

Comment: Sure Vince, anyway, I'm looking for BoBo places, which means that I'm looking for anwers from locals. This website could be work for that? Best, Max

Comment: PS:. I'm not looking for favorite places, I'm looking for locals and (experienced people) answers. Anyway, Thank you for your advice and answers.

Comment: So you want to know where the bobo neighborhood of Amsterdam is?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if "BoBo" is the best term. I'm looking for some advice about good neighborhood to sleep in amsterdam. Maybe local websites to find good places to stay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of Amsterdam, what you're looking for are (ex-)squats. Ex-, because squatting in Amsterdam became illegal in late 2010.  ["What's up with Amsterdam"](http://whatsupwithamsterdam.com/amsterdam-squats/) has some back-story for that.

[image: Squat Vrankrijk in Spuistraat]

One of the most famous ones is [Squat Vrankrijk](http://vrankrijk.org/), which is right in the [center, on Spuistraat](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vrankrijk/@52.37172,4.889342,17z/).

You can find these kind of places in the Canal Belt, Old Center, but especially in [Jordaan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordaan), which also has quite a few hip restaurants etc.

Also, you have to realize that Amsterdam is very small, so staying anywhere in the center you're in walking distance of all these neighborhoods.

Comment: +1 for Jordaan but I would also recommend De Pijp as a semi hipster area.